# PHP array inside $args data

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get users that are either administrator, editor or author as their role from the wordpress database

```
$args = array('orderby' => 'post_count', 'order' => 'DESC','number' => 20, 'role' => 'administrator' );
```

That gets the administrator so i thought this would work

```
$args = array('orderby' => 'post_count', 'order' => 'DESC','number' => 20, 'role' => array('administrator','editor','author') );
```

It returned no results. ?

Comment: `var_export` would be preferable to `print_r`, as it results in a PHP-parseable (hence, more useable) representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass multiple roles in $args, you must call [`get_users`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) once for each role

From the documentation:

> - role - Limit the returned authors to the role specified.

Note that "role" is singular in the parameter description. Call `get_users` once for each role then merge the arrays together of the results